# Android : How to handle stop/pause before MediaPlayer is initialised?

Tags: android, error-handling, media

`public void onClick(View v)` {

```
switch(v.getId()) {

case R.id.button6:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Track playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    player.start(); 
    break;

case R.id.button7:

    player.pause(); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Track Paused...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

case R.id.button8:

    player.stop(); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Track Stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to handle a case where the user tries to press pause or stop while the music hasn't been played yet, perhaps by popping up another message prompting them. How could I edit my code to do so ?

Comment: use mediaPlayer instance and get `isPlaying` property to know either player is playing or not.

Comment: Just disable all the buttons till the player is ready :)